# Uninitialized or NULL pointer in array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array of pointers to structs.

```
struct key {          
  int *data;          
};                    

struct key *entry = NULL;
entry = malloc(sizeof(entry));
```

Reallocated a bit of times:

```
node = realloc(node, (length+1)*sizeof(node[0]));
node[length].data = some_int;
```

In another part of my program, I want to iterate through it. I don't know how much elements it is containing at the moment.

```
for (i=0; &(node[i]) != NULL; i++)
  length = i;
```

But I have infinity loop. Because:

```
(gdb) p node[i]
$1 = {data = 0x0}
```

It seems to like an uninitialized value, but it is not `NULL` pointer.

**How to determine the end of an array?**

**Why it is not `NULL` pointer?**

Comment: `realloc` does not initialise the new memory blocks which it has allocated to 0, if you want that thing you have to do it yourself. But I recommend you to store the "used" length somewhere, and only iterate through that length, since the *"empty"* blocks are don't matter. *(of course store the allocated length somewhere else, to know, how much blocks you have left)*

Comment: `node` is of which type? And if is of `struct key *` why do you assign "*some int*" to a pointer to `int`, that is a `int *`?

Comment: Why don't you use the length that you used to resize?

Comment: As s/he doesn't "*know how much elements it is containing at the moment.*"? @MohitJain

Comment: @alk Keeping `length` last used for `realloc` bundled with `node` sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I like better the approach using a `NULL`-terminated array like proposed in your answer ... @MohitJain

Comment: An "uninitialized" variable can have any value, from null to garbage to a valid address (which may or may not address in item corresponding to the pointer's type).  You can assume *nothing* about an uninitialized pointer, other than you shouldn't use it for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&(node[i])` takes the address of `node[i]`.

So

```
&(node[i]) != NULL
```

will always be true, as **the address of** `node[i]` will **always** be different from `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

`&(node[i])` is same as `node + i` and as long as node is not null and i is not zero, this will be non-null.

If you want to mark end of array, I would suggest always (re)allocate one extra element and initialize pointer member of termination with NULL.

```
struct key *temp = realloc(node, (length+2)*sizeof(node[0]));
if(NULL == temp) {  /* Updated as per suggestion from @alk */
  /* Handle error and return */
}
node = temp;
node[length].data = address_of(some_int);
node[length+1].data = NULL;
```

And later while looping

```
for (i=0; node[i].data != NULL; i++)
  length = i;
```

But an even better solution would be to keep `length` you last used to realloc bundled with `node`. This way you won't need to calculate it using a loop.

Comment: For completeness on how to use `realloc()` it would be nice to see `realloc()` have its result assigned to a temporary pointer, which then is used to test for success and only then will overwrite the pointer which had been passed to `realloc()`. If not doing so a leak is produced if `realloc()` failed.

Comment: @alk Thank you for pointing. man pages say `internally free is called on previous pointer only when memory is moved`.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to express by man-page's quote? However your edit Iike .. :-)

Comment: @alk I meant I understood your point. I did not notice that if `realloc` returns NULL, there would be no move and thus no inclusive free. After the `node` pointer is rewritten there is no way to free mem.